# KeyEvent not firing?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

I have a class World as follows:

```
public class World extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    public boolean left = false, right = false, back = false, fwd = false;

    public World() {
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) left = true;
        if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) right = true;
        if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) fwd= true;
        if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) back = true;
        System.out.println("L:"+left+" R:"+right+" F:"+fwd+" B:"+back);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) left = false;
        if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) right = false;
        if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) fwd= false;
        if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) back = false;
        System.out.println("L:"+left+" R:"+right+" F:"+fwd+" B:"+back);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

This should, theoretically, trigger on key press or key release, however, it does not. Components in the frame are drawing properly.

The frame is being instantiated as follows:

```
World m = new World();
m.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

I can't seem to get the key listener to fire. There are no system outs. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would strongly advise against attaching a key listener to a JFrame, part from all the normal short comings for a KeyListener (must be focused, must have focus), there is a JRootPane and content between the user and the frame, meaning that its possible for the key listener to have no effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you're implementing the interface - but never telling anything that that's important.

You could write this in your constructor:

```
addKeyListener(this);
```

... that would do the right thing, I believe. *Something* has to add the keylistener, basically. Just implementing the interface doesn't automatically make anything start using that implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from not adding the `KeyListener`, `JFrame` is not focusable by default so does not send `KeyEvents` to the window - `KeyEvents` themselves require focus to work. For this reason, the preferred way to interact with `KeyStrokes` in Swing is to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which work without component focus.